# Why was Megillas Taanis written?

Tags: history, jewish-books, writing-printing

In general, oral Torah isn't allowed to be written down ([Gittin 60b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=60b&format=pdf)).

For all generations until the Amorayim (at least according to Rashi), that Halacha was kept.

Yet, according to [Rashi](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=62b&format=text), Megillas Taanis (generally, a list of days one isn't allowed to fast) was written down much earlier, and was the first part of Oral Torah written down!

Couldn't it be kept memorized like all other Mishnayos? Why was it written down?

Comment: Is Megillas Taanis considered Oral Torah? It's not like it was a longstanding tradition. Rashi just calls it "Devar Halacha" meaning it had legal import. I don't know if that makes it prohibited to record in writing.

Comment: Agadata was written down before. I don't have exact sources now but the introductions to Aggadata by different Rabbis printed in the beginning of the Vilna Ein Yaakov bring proofs to this case, including the story of one Rabbi reading Aggadata on Shabbat (If I remember correctly)